# how to count number of files that find command has returned?

Tags: arrays, bash, count, find

Here I got result of 1 instead two files that should have been found:

```
mkdir -p mytestdir001
mkdir -p mytestdir002
LIST=`find -maxdepth 1 -name "mytestdir???"`
echo ${#LIST[@]}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use a dot to say where to start `find . -maxdepth ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `LIST` an array rather than a variable:

```
LIST=( `find -maxdepth 1 -name "mytestdir???"` )
```

Also start using `$()` instead of older ``:

```
LIST=( $(find -maxdepth 1 -name "mytestdir???") )
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use **wordcount** ( `wc` ) :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "mytestdir???" | wc
```

this will give you output like this:

```
2       2      30
```

these are:

- number of lines
- number of words
- number of characters

use **wc -l** to get only the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "mytestdir???" | wc
```

if your real goal is to know the number?

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of the find into a wc and count the lines, given each file is represented by a distinct line - which in my experience is the case with find.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc

example

> [user@machine find]# find . -name "*.file"
>
> ./3.file
>
> ./1.file
>
> ./2.file
>
> [user@machine find]# find . -name "*.file" | wc -l
>
> 3

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | awk '/^mytestdir/{a++}END{print a}' # 2
```

Breakdown:

```
ls | awk '
  # Match every folder / file starting with mytestdir
  /^mytestdir/{a++}
  # Print counted matches
  END{print a}' # 2
```